# Close menu after clicking menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I've done a lot of searching to try and figure out how to do this, and I've found some scripts that do what I'm trying to accomplish, but I don't know how to apply them with my specific wordpress theme, so I thought I'd ask here for some assistance:

I'm using this theme: http://wpbingosite.com/wordpress/kola/

On mobile, when you click a menu link I would like the menu to close. I'm using hash links with my menu that scroll to a particular part of the page and I don't want the user to think nothing happened when they click hash links in the menu.

I found a script like this a few times when searching, but I'm unsure of how to apply it in my specific situation:

```
    $('.menu ul li a').on("click", function (e) {
    burger.click().removeClass("active");
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This example does not define `burger`. It does not show all the code nor how to replicate the issue.

Comment: I've added an exact example of my scenario in response to AstroBoy if you want to check that out

Comment: This does help a little, yet it does not identify the problem code, it is not a minimal example; it's a maximum example where I cannot tell what code is the issue. Also this comment does not explain what steps to take to replicate the issue.What should happen? What is not happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:
A simple boolean should work.

```
//should be closed on startup
var open =false;
$('.menu ul li a').on("click", function (e) {
if(open===true){
document.getElementById('burger').style.display="none";
open=false;
}else{
open=true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the .menu-items and check if the item has children or if it's just a link. If it doesn't have children then remove the active class on the navigation.

```
(function($) {
    $(".menu-item").click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("menu-item-has-children")){
            $(".bwp-canvas-navigation").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
})( jQuery );
```

You should add this into functions.php file and enqueue your script properly:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_menu_function' );
function custom_menu_function(){
     wp_add_inline_script( 'custom-menu-handle', '(function($) {$(".menu-item").click(function () {if(!$(this).hasClass("menu-item-has-children")){$(".bwp-canvas-navigation").removeClass("active");}});})( jQuery );' );
}
```

This hasn't been tested and may require some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll mess around with this and see if I can get it to work.